# Cross-Region replication for Titan backed by DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, database-replication, titan

I'm looking into how to replicate the Titan 1.0.0 database backed by DynamoDB. Normal cross-region replication for DynamoDB can be done through DynamoDB Streams and Lambda, so I wanted to do the same for the Titan tables that are generated on start up.

Step by step process of what I did:

1. Started up a Gremlin server on a NA stack
2. Replicated all the dynamoDB tables that were generated from Titan and its data to a EU region dynamoDB.
3. Tried starting up a Gremlin server on a EU stack after all the tables/data has been replicated from NA to EU.

This error came up when I tried starting up a new Gremlin server on a EU region:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Required size [1] exceeds actual remaining size [0]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.StaticArrayBuffer.require(StaticArrayBuffer.java:80)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.StaticArrayBuffer.getByte(StaticArrayBuffer.java:156)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.util.ReadArrayBuffer.getByte(ReadArrayBuffer.java:67)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idhandling.VariableLong.readUnsigned(VariableLong.java:34)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.idhandling.VariableLong.readPositive(VariableLong.java:80)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.serialize.StandardSerializer.readClassAndObject(StandardSerializer.java:265)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.backend.KCVSConfiguration.staticBuffer2Object(KCVSConfiguration.java:250)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.backend.KCVSConfiguration.get(KCVSConfiguration.java:102)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.configuration.BasicConfiguration.isFrozen(BasicConfiguration.java:93)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1338)
```

Keep in that mind that the replication portion is fine. NA & EU DynamoDB are exact replicas of each other.

#### Questions

1. Does Titan 1.0.0 store region specific information in its tables?
2. Has anyone else tried cross-region replication for Titan?

It seems like the only way to perform cross-region replication for Titan is on the service code level rather than from the built-in functionality from dynamoDB Streams + Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

1. `edgestore` stores all vertices, vertex properties and edges and their properties. `graphindex` is where all composite indexes of vertex and edge properties are stored. These indexes only support equality lookups. `systemlog` is Titan's system log and logs things like schema changes. `txlog` is the transaction log which you can optionally make Titan write to before committing work to the `edgestore`. `titan_ids` stores the id range leases for each UNIQUE_MACHINE_ID assigned to Titan servers as they start up. Finally, `system_properties` stores things like the graph schema (property types, multiplicity, indexes, etc).
2. I have never actually implemented a Titan Cross-Region replication solution, even though I know it is possible.